# How to count object's number in array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a function which create the same objects (with different values of ID, task and point) and push it to array Box. And i want to get each number of object, and show it to user on page. 1,2,3,4,5,6.... How to do it?

```
box: [{
id: shortid.generate(),
task: action.task,
point: false
}]
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you're talking about?

Comment: Added. But there's a fucntion which create the same objects, but with own properties, and I want to show to user number of object.

Comment: Can you provide where do you use arr.length?

Comment: Code will be help full but the answer will probably involve [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: @vlad-grigoryan I'm using arr.length in component which created by function.

Comment: do you just want to add the serialNumber prop to your objects?

Comment: Do you want to sum the values of each `id`? What exactly to you mean by "count objects number in array"?

Comment: @EugenSunic, I just want to show object's number on the web page. For example in To-Do-List. The first  = 1 number, the second task = 2 number

Comment: All you want is to get the `index` of object in an array. And like Eugen Sunic comment, `array.map((item, index)=>{})` has index parameter. check:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to add sequence number to each of your object:

```js
const result = [{
  id: '2s3wf4',
  task: 'task1',
  point: false
}].map((x, i) => ({
  ...x,
  serialNumber: i + 1
}));


console.log(result)
```

Comment: There is a function which create the same objects (with different values of ID, task and point) and push it to array Box. And i want to get each number of object, and show it to user on page. 1,2,3,4,5,6....

Comment: @БогданЧубко please update you description then of what exactly you want it's a little bit unclear...

Comment: I told you above what I need.